# Mustache JS Table Striping

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

I have started to use "Mustache JS" some hours ago. I wonder if there a way to add a class in a tr in order to make the table striped. I know I can detect if the variable's value is null or undefined, but this is not the case. There will always be a value in the variable. Is there any way to do this?

I got the following code up and running:

**The template:**

```
template = "\
        {{#tr}}\
            <tr>\
                <td>{{tit}}</td>\
                <td>{{ord}}</td>\
                <td>{{prazo}}</td>\
                <td>{{id}}</td>\
            </tr>\
        {{/tr}}";
```

**The View:**

```
view = {
                "tr" : [
                    {
                        id : val.ID, 
                        ord : val.Ordem, 
                        prazo : val.Prazo, 
                        tit : val.Título
                    }
                ]
            };
```

I´m aware that I can set a function in the view. But dunno how to properly set a mod inside it , for the striping. Any help would be great.

Comment: CSS3 makes it easier if that's an option: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: I know it. But this is something that have to work on ie7. I know I could easily do that using jquery $('tr:nth-child()'), but I´m trying a diferent approach this time ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this like this:

**The template:**

```
template = "\
        {{#tr}}\
            <tr class="{{even_or_odd}}">\
                <td>{{tit}}</td>\
                <td>{{ord}}</td>\
                <td>{{prazo}}</td>\
                <td>{{id}}</td>\
            </tr>\
        {{/tr}}";
```

**The View: (something like this, assuming you can set a value for iteratorValue)**

```
var interatorValue == 0;
// your other code
view = {
                "tr" : [
                    {
                        id : val.ID, 
                        ord : val.Ordem, 
                        prazo : val.Prazo, 
                        tit : val.Título,
                        even_or_odd: ((iteratorValue % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd')
                    }
                ]
            };
iteratorValue++;
```

Then add css for `tr.odd` and `tr.even`.

Comment: Nice one. I´ll give it a shot.